# Using ViewModel constructor instead of ViewModelProvider to be able to get data from Room database based on parameters

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-room, android-livedata

When using Room database with ViewModel and LiveDate based on this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/) in order to use queries with parameter I didn't find any solution so *I tried to create another constructor for both view model class and repository class* but I noticed that in CodeLab **they don't use view model constructors at all** and instead they use view model provider so I changed it and used 
`new StoryViewModel(getApplication(),"Fiction");` 
instead of 
`new ViewModelProvider(this).get(StoryViewModel.class);`

I don't know if there's anything wrong with this or not. 
*It works fine now*, but if it's the way **why don't we use this always?** 
And why do we use view model provider?

If what I did is wrong then how can I retrieve data from db based on parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not use directly viewModel constructor because the system creates the viewModel or gets it from cache. If you want to pass parameter to the viewModel constructor you should use a viewModel factory like this:

```
class ViewModelFactory(params) : ViewModelProviders.Factory {

     override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
          return modelClass.getConstructor(params::class.java).newInstance(params);
     }

}

...

override fun onCreate(...) {

  viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactory(params)).get(MyViewModel::class.java)s
}
```

Comment: I use Java for this. I got _NoSuchMethodException_ for **getConstructor** : ```return modelClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(this.genre);```

Comment: You should return the instance of ViewModel directly without using the modelClass.

Comment: Thank you. I used it like this : ```if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(StoryViewModel.class)) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T t = (T) new StoryViewModel(getApplication(),this.genre);
                return t;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");``` and it works fine. But I got error on another part. I'm working on it.

Comment: I have multiple recyclerviews in one activity and each one of them has to get populated with different data. **new ModelViewProvider** only works once so I can't use multiple factories or same factory with different constructors. So do know how can I do this?

Comment: If i understood what you mean, you should get different data in the same activity. I guess you can add in the viewmodel one LiveData for each RecyclerView. You have to instantiate all LiveData in the same constructor.

Comment: That's correct and I did that. But the problem is that whenever I want to get data I have to pass all parameters to the factory while they are not necessary.

Comment: Is this case it is possible implement some methods in the ViewModel that accept parameters and return the correct LiveData.

Comment: Works like a charm. No need to any additional constructors for viewmodel or repository classes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example, built with knowledge I gained from Pierluigi's answer:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: ContactViewModel

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        activity?.let { activity ->
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
                activity,
                MyViewModelFactory(
                    "mode value",
                    "nickname value"
                )
            ).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw AssertionError("Unable to get parent activity from fragment")
    }
}

class MyViewModelFactory(val mode: String, val nickname: String) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
        modelClass.getConstructor(String::class.java, String::class.java)
            .newInstance(mode, nickname)
}

class MyViewModel(val mode: String, val nickname: String) : ViewModel()
```